# C# Async Duplex Named Pipes Stop Working After x Amount of Packets

Tags: c#, pipe, ipc, named-pipes, named

Im using Async Duplex Named Pipes to send messages between Three processes.

A sender, a buffer and a receiver. The Buffer has two instances of the example code relating to one pipe coming in from the receiver and one going out to the receiver.

With one instance it runs perfectly for as long as i want.

With two instances in the buffer it works fine and quick like i expect, until after running for around 10 mins at 2000 packets per second, one of the server pipes stops working, there is no exceptions, no breaks, no information whatsoever except that the server pipe just seems to close without warning.

Has anyone ever encountered issues like this?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Test_Processor
{
    public class MessageHandler
    {

        //Transmit Pipe
        NamedPipeClientStream TXPipe;
        //Receive Pipe
        NamedPipeServerStream RXPipe;

        //Store Pipe Names
        string _TXName;
        string _RXName;

        //Read Buffer to store Read Data
        byte[] ReadBuffer = new byte[1040];
        //Write Buffer to store write data
        byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[1040];

        //Store for the latest message received
        public byte[] ReceivedMessage;

        //Latest error message received
        public string ErrorMessage = "";

        //Time of the last messages
        public DateTime LastMessageReceived = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
        public DateTime LastMessageSent = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);

        //Boolean connected variable
        public Boolean IsConnected = false;

        //Custom Events
        public event EventHandler OnReceivedData;
        public event EventHandler OnError;
        public event EventHandler OnDisconnect;


        //Create instance
        public MessageHandler(string TXName, string RXName)
        {
            try
            {

                //Create Received Pipe
                RXPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(RXName, PipeDirection.In, 10, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
                //Create Transmit Pipe
                TXPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", TXName, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough);

                //Store the names
                _TXName = TXName;
                _RXName = RXName;

                //Put the listener in a thread to keep everything else running
                Thread WorkerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListener));
                WorkerThread.IsBackground = true;
                WorkerThread.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                ErrorHandler(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }


        //Start Listener waits for the next connection
        public void StartListener()
        {
            try
            {
                //Begin the async call
                RXPipe.BeginWaitForConnection(new AsyncCallback(WaitForConnectionCallBack), RXPipe);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                ErrorHandler(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        //Callback for the async callback
        private void WaitForConnectionCallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the pipe
                NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = (NamedPipeServerStream)iar.AsyncState;
                // End waiting for the connection
                pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(iar);
                //wait for data to be read
                BeginRead(pipeServer);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        //Begin read event to begin receiving data
        private void BeginRead(NamedPipeServerStream Pipe)
        {
            // Asynchronously read a request from the client
            bool isConnected = Pipe.IsConnected;
            if (isConnected)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Pipe.BeginRead(pd.data, 0, pd.data.Length, OnAsyncMessage, pd);
                    Pipe.BeginRead(ReadBuffer, 0, 1040, OnAsyncMessage, Pipe);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    isConnected = false;
                }
            }

            if (!isConnected)
            {
                //not connected so kill the pipe
                Pipe.Close();
                DisconnectHandler(EventArgs.Empty);

            }

        }

        //Async handler for the end of the message
        private void OnAsyncMessage(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // Async read from client completed
            NamedPipeServerStream pd = (NamedPipeServerStream)result.AsyncState;
            //Read all the data
            Int32 bytesRead = pd.EndRead(result);
            if (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                LastMessageReceived = DateTime.Now;
                ReceivedMessage = ReadBuffer;
                //Call  the on received event
                ReceivedData(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            BeginRead(pd);
        }

        //Send the Async Data to Pipe
        public bool SendAsyncData(byte[] SendData)
        {
            try
            {
                //If its not connected connect
                if (!TXPipe.IsConnected)
                {
                    TXPipe.Connect(500);
                }
                //put data in the buffer
                WriteBuffer = SendData;
                //Begin writing to the pipe
                TXPipe.BeginWrite(WriteBuffer, 0, 1040, OnAsyncWriteComplete, TXPipe);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }

        //On Write Complete
        private void OnAsyncWriteComplete(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            //Finished
            PipeStream pipe = (PipeStream)result.AsyncState;
            pipe.EndWrite(result);
            WriteBuffer = new byte[1040];
        }

        //Custom Event Handlers
        protected virtual void ReceivedData(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = OnReceivedData;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void ErrorHandler(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = OnError;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void DisconnectHandler(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = OnDisconnect;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly, the garbage collector removes the instance. In that case, you should use GC.KeepAlive method to hold a reference to an instance.

Comment: The pipe is constantly being hammered at this stage with data, the garbage collector shouldn't come near it, or am i wrong?

Comment: Well i'll be damned, i put a GC.KeepAlive around the WorkerThread in the above code, and it seems to have fixed it, i will do some soak testing to check but for the last 30 mins its been happy. Not sure why garbage collector is cleaning it up in the first place though? hmm

Comment: Cancel that it died after 45mins that time, again no errors no nothing just server stops responding to client

Comment: Most likely, you've simply failed to understand how I/O works on a pipe. Like a `Socket`, you're dealing with a stream of bytes. If you want message-oriented communications, you need to write the code to handle that. Probably you've got code somewhere getting confused by incoming bytes that are grouped differently from in the way they are sent. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, there's not any practical way to give a specific answer.

Comment: It would be hard to post the complete example as there is a large amount of code in the 3 applications. I am handling each message processing within a catch (which it never reaches) so its not failing to parse the bytes, each system sends and acknowledges each message fine, until the server just fails with no apparent reason. I will try and knock up an example